# What could have caused some of the keys of my keyboard to suddenly stop working?

Tags: keyboard, key-binding

I usually use an azerty keyboard configuration and this issue happened on a laptop (ASUS) with windows 10 as an OS.

I recently tried a rather obscure game on steam which required me to switch to qwerty which I did by alt+caps. One I was done I went back to azerty but noticed anomalies. Some of the keys have stopped working even after several reboots.

The non-capital version of all these keys are concerned; "A", "%", "X", "C", "V", "?", ".", "/" and "§". Capitals work fine, as well as Ctrl commands (I can Ctrl-A, Ctrl-X, Ctrl-C or Ctrl-V fine), but only as long as I use ctrl or caps from the left side of the keyboard. The letter C also sometimes (rarely) works, seemingly at random.

I also just noticed that I can type non-capitalized versions of those characters if I hit caps while caps-lock is active. It still is tedious.

Do you have any idea how I can correct this?